# Zend-framework Loading mpdf in a Project

Tags: zend-framework, mpdf

I have a project in **zend 1.12** and I tried to use **composer** and then use **mpdf**, but it did not work, as it always goes to controller, and I am new to Zend-framework.

*[09-Feb-2017 00:32:28 Europe/Kiev] PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\wamp\www\Avala\application\controllers/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Avala\application\controllers\PdfCreatorController.php on line 30*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Just copy mpdf folder inside library/  of zend 1 and then call it as

```
//loading mpdf class from library
 requre_once 'mpdf/mpdf.php';
//call instance of mpdf
$pdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L'); // New PDF object with encoding & page size
```

then its work. do not need any other settings